# Grails gsp: Is there a way to abort once your render a gsp page?

Tags: grails, error-handling, http-status-code-403, gsp

Is there a way from a gsp page (or type library) to abort the html page generation and to call back to a controller method to output a 403 header?

We have a set of scaffolding pages that we use for our admin pages and have modified them to test if the user accessing that page has admin privs. If not we generate an html page indicating 'not an administrator message' (instead of the normal scaffolding code for the page, i.e., edit.gsp).  The problem here is the http response is a 200 and I really want the response status code to be 403.

The controller associated with the domain object is empty except to enable scaffolding and we have generated the scaffolding pages (via grails generate-view cmd) we also have modified these pages to test if the user is an admin.

So my question comes down to once in a gsp page how can we abort and invoke another controller to generate the 403 error header? Is there a way we can do this from the gsp page or would we have to define the controller methods that match the name of the view page and in the controller method test whether the user is an admin and then issue the 403 error?

Would prefer a way to abort the generation of the current gsp page and be able to invoke a different controller to generate a 403 header.

Comment: Why not test in the controller action instead of while rendering the gsp?  Then you could handle the situation much better.

Comment: I agree, the code I inherited  has a controller for the domain object BUT there are no methods. The controller simply has scaffolding set to the name of the domain class and a set of generated CRUD views.   I didn't know if it is possible to add and update method in the controller (for example) and have it render the update view. This would be a lot of work on our part (we have over 100 domain objects). Was hoping that a gsp directive or a way one could do via a type library call.

Comment: Depending on your grails version, you could create a beforeInterceptor closure or class (closure for 3.0.9 and earlier I think?  class for later) that will be run before every action that it matches.  If you let us know what version of Grails you're using I'm sure either I or someone else could help show you how to do that.

Comment: Thanks. We are using grails 2.4.0 ( I know wish we could update).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your best approach here will be to use an interceptor or filter.  I was going to provide an example but there are already really good ones here: https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#interceptors and https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.4/guide/single.html#filters

Basically, either one is code that will be executed before (or after, but in your case: before) a controller action is executed.  You have access to the params, session, etc. so you can perform logic like "is this person an admin".  You can also modify the response, so you could redirect to a "permission denied" page or set status to 403 or whatever you need to do.

Comment: Thanks...I think we'll have more than one controller that this will applied to and as such, a filter will be a better approach. We will also be having to code up some 'after' filters to generate some additional response header content. so I believe this will be the right approach.

Comment: FYI for when you upgrade, or for anyone else in this situation: In Grails 3, the same thing can be accomplished via Interceptors: http://docs.grails.org/3.3.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#interceptors

Comment: Daniel, just a follow up question. I was able to easily create a filter and was able to add additional headers (another issue we had). I see that from the filter object that I have access to the request, response, params, flash and a few other objects. My concern is that when the GSP paged has determined an unauthorized access to a page, how can the GSP flag that page such that the filter can quickly detect that page and alter the status code to 403. The GSP page has rendered that page with a status code of 200 and we are using the filter (after) to alter the status code to a '403'. Thanks